# Is it possible to force jQuery.jScrollPane to always show a vertical scroll-bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

Is it possible to force [jQuery.jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to always show a vertical scroll-bar?

e.g. hidden setting, API function?

Preferably without touching the content pane, its height etc.

Comment: it depends... can you provide some html or a link, please? I think that a function should be ok, but a need to see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't currently possible with jScrollPane. There is an open feature request for it though:

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues#issue/8

As a workaround for now you could place an element with a min-height directly inside your scrollpane to force the scrollbar like in this example:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/vitch/5D8sR/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

another method which I've confirmed will work is to add a new parameter "alwaysShowScroll:true" and make two changes in jquery.jscrollpane.js:

~line 176, change `if (!(isScrollableH || isScrollableV)) {`
to `if (!(isScrollableH || isScrollableV || settings.alwaysShowScroll)) {`

~line 241, change `if (isScrollableV) {`
to `if (isScrollableV || settings.alwaysShowScroll) {`

Comment: btw, this is not my solution, it's https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/8#issuecomment-4590234

Comment: This worked for me. Lines `186` & `263` are the ones I needed to change.