# jScrollPane always show vertical scroll bar

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

Is there a way to force the jquery jScrollPane to always show the vertical scroll bar now?  I saw a post about adding an element to the pane with a min-height to force it but that was a year or so ago. I've also seen posts about adding VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS to the constructor but that seems to only be for JAVA and not jquery.  Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245551/jquery-jscrollpane-is-it-possible-to-force-always-show-vertical-scrollbar