# Custom scroll bar using jscrollpane

Tags: javascript, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm trying first time to use `jscrollpane` but without success. In this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/jxYb4/)** I'm using the example at **[this page](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html#download)** to replicate the simplest use of `jscrollpane`, which is:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

What I would like is the scrollbar to stay always visible, so I use `overflow:scroll;` in my fiddle. However as soon as I had the above js code it disappears.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245551/jquery-jscrollpane-is-it-possible-to-force-always-show-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: @Aletheios you right, thanks I found there the solution.